# Сравнение массивов как множеств, проверка на одинаковые элементы

Tags: sql, массивы, postgresql, множества

(Вопрос о *PostgreSQL* 12+.)

Нужно проверить, что в двух массивах находятся одинаковые элементы;
порядок элементов не важен.  Можно сделать это с помощью комбинации
операторов `@>` и `<@`:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY[1, 2] @> ARRAY[2, 1]
   AND ARRAY[1, 2] <@ ARRAY[2, 1]
;
-- Output:
--   t
SELECT ARRAY[1, 2] @> ARRAY[3, 1]
   AND ARRAY[1, 2] <@ ARRAY[3, 1]
;
-- Output:
--   f
SELECT ARRAY[1, 2] @> ARRAY[3, 1, 2]
   AND ARRAY[1, 2] <@ ARRAY[3, 1, 2]
;
-- Output:
--   f
```

Есть ли другие способы?  Какой способ быстрее?  Есть ли другие типы,
которые для хранения множеств подойдут лучше массивов?

Comment: Если порядок отсуствует, то следует проверять все 2xNxN вариантов. Если совпало всё (кол-во совпадений 2xNxN), то массивы одинаковые. Оптимизация: если размер массивов разный, то они не равны.

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен, но кажется такой метод должен сработать:

```
SELECT uniq(sort(array1)) = uniq(sort(array2));
```

т.е. сортируем каждый массив, оставляем лишь уникальные элементы и сравниваем. Но тут требуется intarray подключить. Подробнее можно в [официальном хэлпе](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/intarray.html) почитать.

Comment: Это не работает для массивов с другими типами и в ответе нету скоростных характеристик.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите получить результат пересечения двух массивов то удобно развернуть один массив через функцию [UNNEST](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/functions-array) и полученный результат сравнить со вторым массивом, таким образом вы получите массив пересечений. При этом вы можете избежать при необходимости повторяющихся пересечений элементов массива воспользовавшись директивой DISTINCT и упаковать при необходимости результат в итоговый массив через агрегатную функцию array_agg:

```
SELECT DISTINCT aa.id FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[1,1,2,3,45,67,8,8]) AS aa (id) WHERE aa.id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,56,56,56,56]);
+====+
| id |
+====+
| 1  |
| 3  |
| 2  |
+----+

SELECT array_agg(aa.id)::int[] FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[1,2,3,45,67,8,8]) AS aa (id) WHERE aa.id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,56,56,56,56]);
+===========+
| array_agg |
+===========+
| {1,2,3}   |
+-----------+
```

[Пример кода на SQLize](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/ead1f8998f57a9f00c43427641da1873/)